# Update a composed entity in greenDao

Tags: greendao

Let say i have a business domain in which there are two entities, Survey and Question,  in OOP terms,  the Survey has QuestionsList, the greenDao generation  getQuestions method which returns a list of questions resolving 1:M relation from Survey to Question, but there is no method like setQuestions( questionList)  which will take a list of question to update.  How can i update the questionList for the Survey entity ?

Answer (score 1):

you can use:

```
getQuestions().add(Question);
```

but for setting Question parent you should set ParentId for your Question and then add it to QuestionList of Survey. ParentId is the foreign-key of Question which links a question to a survey.
Remember that you must store Question after these changes.

Comment: Thank you for the help, so you are suggesting something like the CoreData( in IOS) functionality. Will try it out.